# Updating a view using powershell

Tags: list, powershell, list-view, view

I have created a list and added some new fields in my sharepoint site. I now want to add my new fields onto the All Items view using Powershell is this possible?
I tried :

```
$viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$viewFields.Add("Title")
$viewFields.Add($myFieldPrivacyStatementurl)
$viewFields.Add($myFieldIsActive)
$viewFields.Add($myFieldSortOrder)

#
# View Name
$viewName = “All Privacy Statements”
#
# Finally – Provisioning the View
$myListView = $myList.Views.Add($viewName, $viewFields, "", 100, $True, $False)
#

$myListView.DefaultView = $True
$myListView.Update()
#
$myList.OnQuickLaunch = $True
$myList.Update()
```

But this just adds a new all items view
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the web and list:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$l = $w.Lists["My list"];
```

This is how you select the view "All items":

```
$view = $l.Views | ? { $_.Title -eq 'All items' }
```

Then just add fields:

```
$view.ViewFields.Add($hereGoesFieldName);
```

And update view:

```
$view.Update();
```

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve ***All Items*** view by using `$myList.DefaultView` if it is a default view or by using the index `$myList.Views["All Items"]`. Then add fields to it and finally update it.

```
$defaultView = $myList.DefaultView;
// Repeat this line for all fields
$defaultView.ViewFields.Add($myList.Fields["FieldName"]);

$defaultView.Update();
```