# Change view (columns) for Pages, Documents, Images libraries for entire site collection

Tags: 2013, document-library, list-view, column, site-collection

I want to change the current views (when you go to, for example, "Site Content > Pages") on Pages, Documents, Images libraries with a new set of columns so that all 100+ subsites in my site collection will all have a uniform set of columns when you go to view the Pages library (or Documents library, or Images library).

How should I go about doing this? For example when I go to mysite.sharepoint/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx

mysite.sharepoint/SUBSITE-1/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx

mysite.sharepoint/SUBSITE-1/SUBSITEOFSUBSITE/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx

mysite.sharepoint/SUBSITE-2/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I want all of these particular views to have the same set of columns.

Currently, all 100+ subsites have a varying assortment of columns.

Thanks,
Sung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using PowerShell

1. First get all Pages libraries in the Site Collection. For that you can use SPSiteDataQuery as explained in - [List all Pages Libraries using PowerShell and SPSiteDataQuery?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71361/list-all-pages-libraries-using-powershell-and-spsitedataquery)
2. Once you have the Library object. You can modify the view as explained [Updating a view using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104676/updating-a-view-using-powershell)

Final code will look something similar

```
$siteCollectionUrl = "http://sp2010"
$site =new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteCollectionUrl)
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteDataQuery
$query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection'>"
$query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' />"
$results = $site.rootweb.GetSiteData($query)
foreach($row in $results.rows)
{
  $listId = $row["ListId"]
  $webId = $row["WebId"]
  $childWeb = $site.OpenWeb([GUID]($webId))
  $pagesList = $childWeb.Lists[[GUID]($listId)];
  $view = $l.Views | ? { $_.Title -eq 'All items' }
  $view.ViewFields.Add($hereGoesFieldName);
  $view.Update();
  $childWeb.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()
```